# Angular Error: Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename file.svg

Tags: css, angular, svg

I have this `css` in my `.component.scss` file

```
.bg {
  background: url("../../../../assets/images/file.svg") center center no-repeat;
}
```

and there's just an svg file in that path, so whenever i change anything in that svg (i.e. `fill` attribute) I'm getting this error

```
Error: Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename file.svg
```

None of SO questions matched my case.

When running `ng serve` again it works fine, but why is this happening?

Comment: what angular version are you using ? are you facing this issue when you update any other components ? there seems to be an old [issue here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9732) related to how angular generates maps

Comment: @ModarNa - I'm using `Angular 12.x`, and i have seen this link, it's more like an issue with `webpack.config.js` which is irrelevant because it's a `warning` there, whereas it's an `error` here.

Comment: does the issue persists if you for example rename the file to file1.svg after updating it ?

Comment: @ModarNa - Wow.. this dark, evil magic actually worked!

Comment: I guess the file is being cached on the browser or the angular server and when you update it it loads another one to the cache generating the error,  renaming maybe a temporal fix until you get another answer or find out what's the real cause.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to delete the `.angular` folder and run `ng serve` again.

Comment: Fixed ! I've deleted .angular folder and everything went well, thanks !