# How to fix Angular "Error: Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename file.svg" without deleting .angular files

Tags: angular, webpack, caching, build

[Angular Error: Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename file.svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778377/angular-error-conflict-multiple-assets-emit-different-content-to-the-same-file)

According to the answers to the above question, it can be solved by removing the `.angular` file.

When the `.angular` file is removed, the build process takes a long time because it is not cached.

So I want to find a more fundamental solution. Is this an issue that can only be resolved by removing the `.angular` file every time?

Resolved the error by removing the `.angular` file. However, the downside is that the build process takes a long time.

Comment: the error say you that you have two files with the same name in different folders that in angular.json makes that copy to assets folder.